# Is Module pattern in javascript worth using?

Tags: javascript, oop, module, prototype

AFAIK understand about module pattern in javascript, it is used to create a namespace where variables and functions become private to that namespace so as to save them from inadvertent manipulation. E.g. Consider the following code:

```
var isTouchDevice = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement;
//some code...
if(isTouchDevice == 1) {
  alert("You are using a touchscreen device");
}
```

In the above code if by mistake I had skipped one equal sign in the if condition as `if(isTouchDevice = 1)` then that would pollute the whole code and any further conditions that check the value of `isTouchDevice` will give false result. AFAI the module pattern is supposed to solve these kind of issues. E.g.  we can make `isTouchDevice` only readable that is read-only thing. This is what I think the modular code will be:

```
var userAgent = function() {                
var TouchDevice = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement;    
function isTouchDevice() {
    return TouchDevice;
}            
return { ifTouchDevice: isTouchDevice };                
}();
```

Now if I want to check whether the device is touch screen then I would do:

`if(useragent.ifTouchDevice())` or `if(useragent.ifTouchDevice() == 1)`

Now even we inadverdantly change `useragent.ifTouchDevice()` such as `if(useragent.ifTouchDevice = 1)`, `TouchDevice` will remain immutable and will always give correct value. So far so good. Now My question is,

- We will be using `if(useragent.ifTouchDevice() == 1)` everywhere to check for touch screen device and think that module pattern will save us. Then if `useragent.ifTouchDevice` has been assigned incorrect value then all the `if` conditions checking for touch device will still go wrong. We have just made `TouchDevice` immutable but still `useragent.ifTouchDevice` is not immutable and acts as a global variable which can be polluted. So what is the advantage of Module pattern?

Comment: A fews other benefits I quite like is, the option to use property accessors using the object literal syntax, and the ability to "inherit" from multiple ancestors.

Comment: No. The *only* point of the module pattern is to create a *local namespace* (scope) for variables and functions. Making them immutable is a completely different topic.

Comment: This `if(isTouchDevice = 1)` is a typographical mistake and it will always exist no matter what.  if I do `if(useragent.ifTouchDevice() = 1)`, it will not override any value but will bypass condition as it will always be true.